# Go Blowfish weird stuff

Tags: go, blowfish

I have the following function which encodes the string using Blowfish.If I put just a string to byte array it works. The problem is with line
    cipher.Encrypt(enc[0:],src)

```
func BlowFish(str string){
    key := []byte("super secret key")

    cipher,err := blowfish.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    //very weird that I get index out of range if I insert a var
    src :=[]byte(str+"\n\n\n")

    var enc [512]byte
    cipher.Encrypt(enc[0:],src)

    fmt.Println("Encoded",enc)

    var decrypt[8] byte
    cipher.Decrypt(decrypt[0:],enc[0:])

    result:=bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    result.Write(decrypt[0:8])

    fmt.Println(string(result.Bytes()))
}
```

I don't understand the problem

Comment: Please show us your broken code, not your working code.

Comment: here is the broken version

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you get? There's no reason your `src :=` line should be failing. See [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N4h7onxGq7).

Comment: I get index out of range on cipher.Encrypt(enc[0:],src)

Comment: I tried to make enc of size 2048 and 4096, it doesn't help

Comment: It's weird that when I replace in src str with the string I input e.g("my str"+"\n\n\n") it works

Comment: It is best not to use Blowfish, even its creator now uses AES.

Answer (score 3):

While this may result in an error using Go Blowfish, it is correct. [Blowfish](https://www.schneier.com/academic/blowfish/) is a 64-bit (read 8-byte) block cipher. As you've discovered, not only does your string have to be 8 bytes with padding, but any data you wish to encrypt must be padded so that all blocks are equal to eight bytes.

To do so, you should be checking the modulus of your data, and padding the remainder so that the length of the data is a multiple of 8, like so.

```
func blowfishChecksizeAndPad(pt []byte) []byte {
    // calculate modulus of plaintext to blowfish's cipher block size
    // if result is not 0, then we need to pad
    modulus := len(pt) % blowfish.BlockSize
    if modulus != 0 {
        // how many bytes do we need to pad to make pt to be a multiple of 
        //blowfish's block size?
        padlen := blowfish.BlockSize - modulus
        // let's add the required padding
        for i := 0; i < padlen; i++ {
            // add the pad, one at a time
            pt = append(pt, 0)
        }
    }
    // return the whole-multiple-of-blowfish.BlockSize-sized plaintext
    // to the calling function
    return pt
}
```

Comment: It is best not to use null padding, it is not compatible with binary data. Instead use {PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Comment: In the context of the question, it's fine as he is encoding a string, not binary data, and the null character can be stripped off as whitespace.

Comment: Downvoting because I disagree that strings need PKCS7 padding, especially in the context of example code which should be kept simple, just makes you look petty. :|

Comment: Null padding presents interoperability problems because most encryption implementations do not support null padding. This has been a major issue with PHP mcrypt interoperability. PKCS#7 implementation cn be as simple: `pt = append(pt, padlen)`. Using PKCS#7 padding can help avoid future interoperability. Further one should consider future readers, who will not have the same context as this question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found what's wrong. cypher.Encrypt accepts byte array of length 8. But the length of byte array []byte(str+"\n\n\n") is 4. That's why I get an index out of range. If I have an array []byte("My str to encode"+"\n\n\n"). It's len is len of 2 strings. The solution for now is to add more \n chars to have the length of array str+"\n....\n" >=than 8